Configure an up-to-date clangd?
I can't get my emacs lsp to use a newer clangd - I have this in my ~/.emacs:
(custom-set-variables
 '(lsp-clangd-version "19.1.0"))

And that version is indeed available here as the documentation for lsp-clangd-version says - how do I get it to actually use the newer version?

Have you tried invoking lsp-install-server? An alternative approach would be to download clangd binary to a directory that is included in your $PATH. That will ensure it gets picked by lsp-mode.
